# The phone return NULL when I want to get the phone number

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Some phones return `null` when I want to get the phone number. In other phones I get the phone number.

Why is this happening?

The code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

And:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
String test3;
String test2 = "";

if(mPhoneNumber.length() > 10) {
    test3 = "0"+mPhoneNumber.substring(4, 13);
}
else {
    test3 = mPhoneNumber;
}
for(int i = 0; i<test3.length(); i++) {
    if (String.valueOf(test3.charAt(i)).equals("-") || String.valueOf(test3.charAt(i)).equals(" ")) {
    }
    else {
        test2 += String.valueOf(test3.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

test2 does not return anything.

Comment: `getLine1Number` attempts fto fetch the msisdn from the SIM, some carriers will not prepopulate this.

Answer (score 1):

Not all SIM cards store the phone number, and hence it cannot be retrieved on all phones.

You can ask the user to enter it manually (and confirm it using an SMS), if you really need it every time.

You can check to see if your SIM has the number stored by checking `Settings -> About Phone -> Status -> My phone number`

Comment: Hey,I checked it and it happens when Settings -> About Phone -> Status -> My phone number is empty.It write "Unknow".
What to do?

Comment: @Ron There's nothing you can do. It's a carrier issue

Answer (score 0):

You also need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Also, it depends on the SIM card. The phone may not have a number. Generally you get the phone number that is in About device>Status>My phone number.

Comment: Hey,I checked it and it happens when Settings -> About Phone -> Status -> My phone number is empty.It write "Unknow".
What to do?

Comment: I don't know why that is empty, my old phone had the same problem but I am sure you won't be able to fix it programmatically.